# Best way to represent multilingual database on orientdb

Tags: graph-databases, orientdb

I have a MySQL database to support a multilingual website where the data is represented as the following:

**table1**

```
id
is_active
created
```

**table1_lang**

```
table1_id
name
surname
address
```

What's the best way to achieve the same on graph database? 
Create two classes and then define a relation between them, is this the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You could have something like this:

```
create class Table1 extends V
create property Table1.isActive boolean
create property Table1.created datetime

create class Table1Lang extends V
create property Table1Lang.name string
create property Table1Lang.surname string
create property Table1Lang.address string

create class Relation extends E


create vertex Table1 set isActive = true, created = sysdate()
// returns #12:0
create vertex Table1Lang set name = 'name', surname = 'surname', address = 'address'
// returns #13:0

create edge Relation from #12:0 to #13:0
```

As you can see, I've remove the ids from both tables and use the Record ID's instead. If performance matters to you, you should do the same.

If, e.g., you want the record from **Table1Lang** that's related to some record (let's say **#12:0**) from **Table1**, you can:

```
select expand(out('Relation')) from #12:0
// returns #13:0
```